# uninitialized constant Test::Unit::UI::XML (NameError) in Rails (or Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I'm trying to create an xml runner to make a result report of Rails unit testing. Here is a code I have:

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'test/unit/ui/console/testrunner'

class FastFailRunner < Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner
  def add_fault(fault)
    @faults << fault
    nl
    output("%3d) %s" % [@faults.length, fault.long_display])
    output("--")
    @already_outputted = true
  end

  def finished(elapsed_time)
    nl
    output("Finished in #{elapsed_time} seconds.")
    nl
    output(@result)
  end
end

Test::Unit::AutoRunner::RUNNERS[:fastfail] = proc do |r|
  FastFailRunner
end
```

When I run it as `TESTOPTS="/home/alex/RubymineProjects/app2/test/unit/runner.rb --runner=xml" rake test`

... I get an error (pretty weird error)

```
/home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant Test::Unit::UI::XML (NameError)
    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/test-unit-2.5.2/lib/test/unit/runner/xml.rb:5:in `block in <module:Unit>'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/test-unit-2.5.2/lib/test/unit/autorunner.rb:389:in `[]'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/test-unit-2.5.2/lib/test/unit/autorunner.rb:389:in `run'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/test-unit-2.5.2/lib/test/unit/autorunner.rb:58:in `run'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/test-unit-2.5.2/lib/test/unit.rb:501:in `block in <top (required)>'
gem install minitest
/home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/test-unit-2.5.2/lib/test/unit/runner/xml.rb:5:in `block in <module:Unit>': uninitialized constant Test::Unit::UI::XML (NameError)
    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/test-unit-2.5.2/lib/test/unit/autorunner.rb:389:in `[]'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/test-unit-2.5.2/lib/test/unit/autorunner.rb:389:in `run'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/test-unit-2.5.2/lib/test/unit/autorunner.rb:58:in `run'
    from /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/test-unit-2.5.2/lib/test/unit.rb:501:in `block in <top (required)>'
Errors running test:units! #<RuntimeError: Command failed with status (1): [/home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin...]>
Errors running test:functionals! #<RuntimeError: Command failed with status (1): [/home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin...]>
```

I tried to require `test/unit/ui/xml/testrunner.rb` but no luck.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in Ruby 1.8.7 you can say:

```
require 'test/unit/ui/console/testrunner'
p Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner # => no problem
```

(There is no such file as `test/unit/ui/xml/testrunner.rb` so I'm not sure what you were up to there.)

Look in the docs in test/unit.rb, there's actually sample code showing you how to do this require: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit.html.

However, the problem is that you are in Ruby 1.9.3. There is no /test/unit in Ruby 1.9.3! Well, there is, but it's just a compatibility layer for basic tests; there is certainly no test/unit/ui/console/testrunner, and no module/class `Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner`.

Instead, there's minitest. You can read the docs on minitest to see how to make a test runner. http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/

Comment: What do you mean? I have exactly the same code `require 'test/unit/ui/console/testrunner'`.

Comment: Sorry, blew it on the first go. I hadn't spotted that line and I hadn't realized you were using 1.9.3. I've, uh, improved my answer.

Comment: I don't want to use anything else. I want to use Test::Unit. Is it possible to generate a result xml (or plain) file using it?

Comment: Well, ok if I'm using minitests, how can I generate result file?

Comment: "I want to use Test::Unit". Then use it: http://test-unit.rubyforge.org/. But the reason for your "pretty weird error" is that you're not using it now. I believe that is what you asked, yes?

Answer (score 1):

One thing to consider is that Test::Unit was included in the default Ruby 1.8.7 installation.  If you want to use it in with a later version of Ruby then go ahead and install it as a gem.

```
sudo gem install test-unit
```

http://test-unit.rubyforge.org/